# Movable UI Error Qt5

Tags: c++, qt

I'm having some issues with my UI. I'm trying to make it movable but I keep getting random errors. Here is a screenshot of what the error is: `http://prntscr.com/79esqu`

DraggableWindow.cpp code:

```
#include "DraggableWindow.h"

#include <QWidget>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPoint>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <Qt>

DraggableWindow::DraggableWindow(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
, m_captured(false)
, m_last_event_pos(QPoint(0, 0))
{
}

void DraggableWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        m_last_event_pos = event->pos();
        m_captured = true;
    }
}

void DraggableWindow::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(m_captured)
    {
        this->move(this->pos() + (event->pos()-m_last_event_pos));
    }
}

void DraggableWindow::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        m_captured = false;
    }
}
```

DraggableWindow.h code:

```
#pragma once

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QPoint>

class DraggableWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit DraggableWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);

protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event);

private:
    bool m_captured;
    QPoint m_last_event_pos;
};
```

The start off script for mainlauncher.cpp:

```
MainLauncher::MainLauncher(QWidget *parent)
: DraggableWindow(parent)
, ui(Ui::MainLauncher)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

I'm having issues. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have got are linker errors. Seems like your `DraggableWindow.cpp` has not been compiled.

Make sure you have included `DraggableWindow.cpp` in `SOURCES` section of your .pro file and `DraggableWindow.h` in `HEADERS` section.

If they are correctly added in your .pro file, qmake may not have run after you added them. Try `Build->Run Qmake` and then `Build->Rebuild All`